# How to arrange a data table such that a row of category can be transposed as a grouping variable in a column?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, grouping, transpose

[This how the data look originally look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGswE.png)
[This is how I  ultimately want the data to be ararnged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZckl.png)

I want to re-arrange the data in the first four columns ("test1" to "test4") into one column named "response" while having the values in cell correctly corresponds to which test, subject and trial number.

These two pictures are just showing a simplified example, the dataset that I am actually handling is much larger.

Below are the Python codes my friend wrote to have helped me solve the same problem with the actual dataset, I tried to write it in R but failed, so I list them there as a reference.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('cleaned.csv')
# data.head()
# data.columns
ids = data.columns[278:].tolist()
new_data = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['value', 'name1', 'name2'] + ids)
n_data = len(data) - 1
for i in range(278):
    cur_feature = data[[data.columns[i]] + ids].drop(0)
    cur_feature.rename(columns={data.columns[i]: 'value'}, inplace=True)
    cur_feature['name1'] = [data.columns[i]] * n_data
    cur_feature['name2'] = [data.iloc[0, i]] * n_data
    new_data = pd.concat([new_data, cur_feature])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in Python as the simplified example below shows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test1': [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'test2': [11, 12, 13, 14],
                   'subject': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'trial_order': [ 1234, 3421, 4567, 7892]
                   })

print(df)

df2 = df.melt(id_vars = ['subject', 'trial_order'], var_name = 'test_phase', value_name = 'response' )

print(df2)
```

which gives:

```
   test1  test2 subject  trial_order
0      1     11       a         1234
1      2     12       b         3421
2      3     13       c         4567
3      4     14       d         7892

  subject  trial_order test_phase  response
0       a         1234      test1         1
1       b         3421      test1         2
2       c         4567      test1         3
3       d         7892      test1         4
4       a         1234      test2        11
5       b         3421      test2        12
6       c         4567      test2        13
7       d         7892      test2        14
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to reproduce it in R?

Comment: There is a `melt` function in R which does the same `wide to long` re-shaping but I am not familiar enough with R to suggest code. If you cannot get this to work then you could always process in Python Pandas and write out CSV for R if Pandas cannot do whatever you need.